# Model not updating after Ajax call to delete data

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a little POC web app that I'm putting together, and one of my pages is called "ViewAds" (you can imagine what it does). Anyway, for site admins, there is a delete button for each ad, which invokes an ajax call to a controller action, DeleteAd, which simply hits the DAL to delete the item and returns. No redirect, no refresh, nothing.

The Ajax Callback is where I take care of the refresh:

```
success: function(){
url = '@Url.Action("ViewAds","Ad",new{OtherOptionsForDisplayingAdsGo=here})';
window.location.href = url;
}
```

Which hits the DB again for Ads, and should return my view without the deleted Ad.

But instead, the page is displayed with the ad still showing until I refresh it manually. I also noticed that if I set a breakpoint on ViewAds, giving it time to update (I guess), it works fine as well. Anybody know what's going on here?

Here's my ViewAds in case you wanted to see it:

```
public ActionResult ViewAds(string getAllAds = "false")
        {
            bool GetAllAds = bool.Parse(getAllAds);
            List<PostedAD> results;
            if (Session["Location"] == null || GetAllAds)
            {
                DataManager _dataProvider = new DataManager();
                results = _dataProvider.FetchAds();
                ViewData["ViewAllAds"] = "True";
                return View("ViewAds", results);
            }
            else
            {
                string Location = Session["Location"].ToString();
                DataManager _dataProvider = new DataManager();
                results = _dataProvider.FetchAdsByLocation(Location);
                ViewData["ViewAllAds"] = "False";
                return View("ViewAds", results);
            }
        }
```

And delete is pretty intuitive. It just calls my `DataManager.Delete()`  on a particular ad. (it works fine)

So can anyone help out with this? I'm not sure what's going on, though I'd assume it's something to do with ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that I had accidentally left the connection object open within my DAL code on this particular function. Adding:

```
finally
{
    if(conn!=null) conn.Close();
}
```

to the end of my `FetchAds()` method fixed my issue.

If someone would like to explain exactly why that would cause the issue described, I'd gladly accept that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a caching issue. Try busting the cache by appending a random query string parameter:

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("ViewAds", "Ad", new { OtherOptionsForDisplayingAdsGo = here, _ = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() })";
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought of first too, and tried using an OutputCache attribute to force a new page each time, but that didn't do it. Tried this too just now, and no luck.

Comment: Oh then this has to do with your data access code. Did you try debugging and ensured that withing the ViewAds action you are getting fresh data actually?

Comment: Well thats the thing. When I set a breakpoint inside ViewAds or the DAL code, it works just fine, and everything gets updated, so debugging it doesn't really do me a lot of good. Previously, I had the Ajax-invoked action returning a view, and I thought maybe since it's async, it was returning to the callback before it finished rendering. Which would make sense, but then I changed to my current architecture and I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is maybe I'm leaving the connection open somehow without realizing it, and then it isn't actually updated until the GC finds it and gets rid of it. Would that make sense?

Comment: I guess I could just invoke delete and then hide the element via jQuery or something, and then I wouldn't even need a postback. That's probably a better way to do it anyway. But still, I'd love to know what the underlying issue is here.

Comment: No the thing with GC and the connection hardly makes any sense to me.

Comment: Well, I'm using ADO.net and an access db (yeah, I know, access sucks, but this is just a POC), and the changes aren't committed until the connection is closed, right? So if a connection were left open, I would get old results if another connection was made to the same data source. Then, the GC idea might explain why this works only when it gets a little extra time from me setting breakpoints